# Pagination in thumbnail PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli, pagination

I am trying to create a page that shows thumbnails from my database. However i want to create a pagination in case i want to update my database. Only the first 3 table should show in page 1 and so on...

Here is my script in thumbnail

```
<?php
    /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Attempt select query execution
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news limit 3";
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

            echo "<div class=\"container\">";
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "</tr>";
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                echo "<div class=\"col-md-4\">";
                echo "<div class=\"thumbnail\">";  
                echo "<img alt=\"News\" src=\"images/{$row["image"]}\">";
                echo "<div class=\"caption\">";
                echo "<b><h4>{$row["title"]}</b></h4>";
                echo "<p>{$row["caption"]}</p>";
                echo "<p align=\"right\">";
                echo "<a class=\"btn btn-primary\" href=\"{$row["newsupdate"]}\">Read More</a>";
                echo "</p>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
            echo "</table>";

            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else{
            echo "No records matching your query were found.";
        }
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
?>

<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the pagination part of the sql query is absent - you will need to use the current page and the limit together - incrementing the page to proceed/return to previous results. ie: `SELECT * FROM news limit {$currentpage}, 3` - how you determine the total number of records and the various forward/reverse links is more involved

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to paginate the tables that are appearing as a result not?

I think is a good option use the pagination of Bootstrap or Jquery:

https://www.uno-de-piera.com/paginacion-original-con-jquery-y-php/
https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/

You can configure the items shows per page, the style, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to paginate through your recordset, thus limiting the display to a specified number of records at a time, you need to change the sql query to use the `offset` and `total` values for the `limit` clause. Generally pagination uses GET variables to determine the page the user is currently on and this variable is used in the SQL query.

The following is a basic example I just wrote to paginate through a particular recordset - it should be straightforward to utilise the code and alter to suit your particular query.

```
<?php
    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'xxx'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Basic Pagination</title>
        <style>
            #paging{border-top:1px solid black;margin:1rem auto;float:none;clear:both;}
            #paging *{margin:0.5rem 1rem;clear:none!important;display:inline-block;}
            .minimal{margin:0.5rem 0.1rem!important;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='results'>
            <?php
                /* Single user supplied parameter - the PAGE */
                $page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) : 0;


                if( is_numeric( $page ) && $page >= 0 ){

                    $rpp = 10;  /* Records Per Page */
                    $offset = $page * $rpp; /* paging offset */

                    /*
                        In order to determine the paging you need to know the total number of records available 
                        that are returned by the query with any given WHERE clause. The sub-query therefore uses
                        the same WHERE clause and returns a number to be used later.

                        Edit the sql to suit your needs and edit the data that is rendered in the while loop.
                    */
                    $sql="select
                        ( select count(*) from `maps`  where `location_enabled`=1 ) as 'count',
                        `id`,
                        `location_name` as 'name'
                        from `maps`
                        where `location_enabled`=1
                        limit {$offset},{$rpp}";



                    /*
                        Ignoring the possible SQL injection vulnerability - run the query
                    */
                    $results=$db->query( $sql );

                    if( $results && $results->num_rows > 0 ){

                        /* Process the recordset however is appropriate for your use-case */
                        while( $rs=$results->fetch_object() ){

                            /* From sql query, the total number of records that satisfy the "WHERE" clause */
                            $count=$rs->count;

                            /* output data - thumbnails etc etc */
                            echo "<div>{$rs->id} - {$rs->name}</div>";
                        }


                    } else {
                        echo "Error! Unable to fetch results";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Error... Bad foo!";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id='paging'>
            <?php
                /*
                    Calculate links for basic pagination
                    ( First,Previous,Next,Last )
                */
                if( is_numeric( $page ) ){

                    $total_pages = floor( $count / $rpp );

                    $text='First';
                    if( $page == 0 ){
                        echo "<div>$text</div>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<a href='?page=0'>$text</a>";
                    }

                    $text='Previous';
                    if( $page > 0 ){
                        echo "<a href='?page=".max( 0, $page - 1 )."'>$text</a>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<div>$text</div>";
                    }

                    $text='Next';
                    if( $page >= $total_pages ){
                        echo "<div>$text</div>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<a href='?page=".min( $total_pages, $page + 1 )."'>$text</a>";
                    }

                    $text='Last';
                    if( $page==$total_pages ){
                        echo "<div>$text</div>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<a href='?page={$total_pages}'>$text</a>";
                    }


                    /* Generate basic hyperlink for each possible page */
                    for( $i=0; $i <= $total_pages; $i++ ) {
                        echo "<a class='minimal' href='?page={$i}'>".( $i + 1 )."</a>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

    $db->close();

?>
```

Comment: can you put an update to your original question showing what/how you have implemented the pagination system?